# BufferedReader stop the code

Tags: java, exception, text, bufferedreader

Today, I was making a program about BufferedReader. The program is to replace a line by using BufferedReader. But when I ran the program, it crashed without any errors or exceptions. I am confused about that. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class FileReplace {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String path = "/w2.txt";
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    File file = new File(path);
    if(file.exists()) {
        System.out.println("This file is valid.");
        System.out.println("REPLACE WHAT?");
        String OriText = input.nextLine();
        FileReader filepath = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader fileword = new BufferedReader(filepath);
        String[] keyW = new String[4];
        for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
            keyW[i] = fileword.readLine();
            System.out.println(keyW[i]);
        }
        if(isExist(OriText,keyW)) {
            System.out.println("Found! REPLACE WITH WHAT?");
            String Inputword = input.nextLine();
            try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(path);){
                for(int i = 0; i<keyW.length; i++) {
                    String textto = replaceWord(keyW, OriText, Inputword)[i];
                    out.println(textto);
                }
                System.out.print("REPLACED!");
            }
        }

    }else {
        System.out.println("This file is invalid.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    input.close();
}

public static boolean isExist(String a, String[] keyW) {
    boolean status = false;
    for(int i = 0; i<keyW.length; i++) {
        if(keyW[i]==a) {
            status = true;
        }
    }
    return status;
}

public static String[] replaceWord(String[] keyW, String a,String b) {
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<keyW.length; i++) {
        if(keyW[i] == a) {
            index = i;
        }
    }
    keyW[index] = b;
    return keyW;
}
}
```

And this is the file:

```
w2.txt
hello
Die Frau
HelloWorld
Beginnen
```

When I ran the program, the result is

```
This file is valid.
REPLACE WHAT?
hello
hello
Die Frau
HelloWorld
Beginnen
```

And I couldn't reach the next step. Can someone help me to solve this problem? Thanks anyway.

Comment: what is your UseCase?

Comment: Just replace a word

Comment: Your code is complicated to just replace word in file Follow this site http://javaconceptoftheday.com/modify-replace-specific-string-in-text-file-in-java/

Comment: Thanks! But my question about this program is what makes it stop?

Comment: The fact is that it stopped because of the isExist() function. But I have checked it for many times and found no faults.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I have solved this problem. The program stopped because the String a is an object, and it cannot use ==, but should use .equals() function. Thanks!